# Monotonicity of $M$-sequence

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Consider the following definition in the second page of [this article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/da0b/1a3430e4be45119921b8b8a6578b355bb2f6.pdf):

> For any two integers $k,n\ge 1$, there is a unique way of writing
>   $$n=\binom{a_k}{k}+\binom{a_{k-1}}{k-1}+\dots+\binom{a_i}{i}$$
>   so that $a_k > a_{k-1} > \dots > a_i\geq i > 0$. Define
>   $$\partial_{k-1}(n) = \binom{a_k}{k-1}+\binom{a_{k-1}}{k-2}+\dots+\binom{a_i}{i-1}.$$

Is it true that when $k$ is fixed, the function $\partial_{k-1}(n)$ is weakly increasing in $n$? It does not look straightforward to prove this directly, but I assume it has already been shown somewhere.

Comment: Eventually it may be strictly decreasing. Note for n less than k the d function gives a value bigger than n, and for many large n it gives a value smaller than n.  Gerhard "It Needs To Reverse Somewhere" Paseman, 2019.07.04.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I don't think your latter statement implies that the sequence will eventually be strictly decreasing. For example, consider the sequence $2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,\dots$. For $n\leq 3$ the function gives a value bigger than $n$, and for $n\geq 5$ it gives a value smaller than $n$.

Comment: Spellchecker. I typed increasing, and it got changed. Gerhard "Spellcheck Thinks It Is Helping"  Paseman, 2019.07.04.

Comment: $\partial_{k-1}(n)$ is the least possible number of $(k-1)$-element faces of an (abstract) simplicial complex with $n$ $k$-element faces, as follows from Theorem 1.1 of the proposer's link. From this monotonicity is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that this ordering is lexicographic. We may induct on $k$. The base $k=1$ is clear. Assume that $n>m$ and
\begin{align*}
n=\binom{a_k}{k}+\binom{a_{k-1}}{k-1}+\ldots+\binom{a_i}{i},a_k>a_{k-1}>\ldots>a_i\geqslant i,\\
m=\binom{b_k}{k}+\binom{b_{k-1}}{k-1}+\ldots+\binom{b_j}{j},b_k>b_{k-1}>\ldots>b_j\geqslant j.
\end{align*}
If $a_k>b_k$, then 
$$
\partial_{k-1}(n)\geqslant \binom{a_k}{k-1}\geqslant 
\binom{b_k+1}{k-1}=\binom{b_k}{k-1}+\binom{b_k}{k-2}=\\
\binom{b_k}{k-1}+\binom{b_k-1}{k-2}+\binom{b_k-1}{k-3}=\ldots=\\
\binom{b_k}{k-1}+\binom{b_k-1}{k-2}+\binom{b_k-2}{k-3}+\ldots+\binom{b_k-k+j+1}{j}+\binom{b_k-k+j+1}{j-1}\geqslant \\
\binom{b_k}{k-1}+\binom{b_{k-1}}{k-2}+\binom{b_{k-2}}{k-3}+\ldots+\binom{b_{j+1}}{j}+\binom{b_{j+1}}{j-1}>\partial_{k-1}(m).
$$
If $a_k=b_k$, they cancel and we use induction. If $a_k<b_k$, then $m>n$ by the same reasoning as above.

Comment: Do you mean $\partial_{k-1}(m)$ instead of $\partial_{k-1}(n)$ in the last line?

Comment: @doe yes, fixed

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard to show that $0 \leq \delta_{k-1}(n)-\delta_{k-1}(n-1) \leq k-1$ and to say when each possible jump happens.

Let me first alter the notation by setting $a_j=j+t_j.$

> For any two integers $k,n\ge 1$, there is a unique way of writing
>    $$n=\binom{k+t_k}{k}+\binom{k-1+t_{k-1}}{k-1}+\dots+\binom{i+t_i}{i}$$
>   so that $i \geq 1$ and $t_k\geq t_{k-1} \geq \dots \geq t_i\geq  0$.
>
> Define
>    $$\partial_{k-1}(n) = \binom{k+t_k}{k-1}+\binom{k-1+t_{k-1}}{k-2}+\dots+\binom{i+t_i}{i-1}.$$

**CLAIM**: Let  $n=\binom{k+t_k}{k}+\binom{k-1+t_{k-1}}{k-1}+\dots+\binom{i+t_i}{i}>1$ as above.

If $t_i = 0$ then

- $n=\binom{k+t_k}{k}+\binom{k-1+t_{k-1}}{k-1}+\dots+\binom{i+1+t_{i+1}}{i+1}+\binom{i}{i}$
- $n-1=\binom{k+t_k}{k}+\binom{k-1+t_{k-1}}{k-1}+\dots+\binom{i+1+t_{i+1}}{i+1}$
- $\delta_{k-1}(n)-\delta_{k-1}(n-1)=i$.

If $t_i>0$  then

- $n=\binom{k+t_k}{k}+\binom{k-1+t_{k-1}}{k-1}+\dots+\binom{i+1+t_{i+1}}{i+1}+\binom{i+t_i}{i}$
- $n-1=\binom{k+t_k}{k}+\binom{k-1+t_{k-1}}{k-1}+\dots+\binom{i+1+t_{i+1}}{i+1}+\binom{i+t_i-1}{i}+\binom{i-1+t_i-1}{i-1}+\cdots+\binom{1+t_i-1}{1}$
- $\delta_{k-1}(n)-\delta_{k-1}(n-1)=0$.

---

Note that if the expansion above for $n$ is according to the requirements then the expansion claimed for $n-1$ also meets the requirement. That it is actually equal to $n-1$  is clear in the case $t_i=0$ and for the case $t_i \gt 0$ follows from this familiar fact:

For $a \gt i$ and $i \geq 1$ we have $$\binom{a}{i}=\binom{a-1}{i}+\binom{a-2}{i-1}+\cdots+\binom{a-i}{1}+\binom{a-i-1}{0}$$ Switching to the $t$ notation:$$\binom{i+t}{i}=\binom{i+t-1}{i}+\binom{i-1+t-1}{i-1}+\cdots+\binom{1+t-1}{1}+1$$

That $\delta_{k-1}(n)-\delta_{k-1}(n-1)=i$ when $t_i=0$ is clear and that $\delta_{k-1}(n)=\delta_{k-1}(n-1)$ when $t_i \gt 0$ follows from writing the same fact as

$$\binom{i+t}{i-1}=\binom{i+t-1}{i-2}+\binom{i-1+t-1}{i-2}+\cdots+\binom{1+t-1}{0}$$